# Create for loop to process multiple rasters in a file using arcpy Clip management

Tags: python, arcpy

I am trying to create a for loop to process (clip) multiple rasters that are in one file using arcpy Clip Management Tool. I first used model builder to create a script with the correct parameters in arcmap. I exported this script and then then updated to add in a loop to process multiple rasters in a folder. When attempting to run I'm getting back an error that None Type object not iterable.   Here is error:
line 6, in `<module>`
for raster in rasterlist:
**TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable**

```
import arcpy
texas_shp = "C:\\user\\Nicole\\data\\gis\\texas.shp"
tx__Name_ = "C:\\user\\Nicole\\date\\clippedimages\\tx_%Name%"
rasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters("C:\\user\\Nicole\\data\\gis\\imagestoclip")
for raster in rasterlist:
for i in range(30):
        arcpy.Clip_management(raster, "-8492199.91815014 -8492199.91793823 1914766.86774716 1213815.0683878", tx__Name_, texas_shp, "-2147483647", "NONE", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
print arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages(0))
```

Comment: First, please paste the full exception with traceback, not just a description of your error.

Comment: `range()` with no arguments?

Comment: Second, you're right that you can't have a `return` statement outside of a function. But I'm not sure what the `return` is supposed to be doing there anyway. If you wrapped that up in a function, it would just return the first element in the loop, which means you could just use `raster = rasterlist[0]` and skip the whole loop. I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: And finally, you've got multiple errors that aren't just "here's what you did wrong" mistakes but "I have no idea what this code is supposed to do, so I can't tell you how to fix it" mistakes. Like the `return`, and the `range()`, and why are you passing things to `Clip_management` that don't seem the be the types of things the docs say it takes?

Comment: The code is supposed to take a series of rasters that are in one file location and loop thru to clip them to the extent of a shapefile that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't export a ModelBuilder to Python and use it as it is.

1. The dynamic `%Name%` notation used in ModelBuilder will not be recognoised in Python.
2. You have to define the workspace of interest prior to running the ListRasters function (check its syntax [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/ListRasters/03q30000005m000000/)).
3. Also, as mentioned  by @abarnet, the `for i in range(30):` line is useless if you want to loop over all rasters in your workspace.
4. If you use a shapefile as clipping geometry, it's not necessary to specify the `rectangle` parameter in the [Clip](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000009n000000) tool.

So your code should look like this:

```
import arcpy, os
texas_shp = "C:\\user\\Nicole\\data\\gis\\texas.shp"
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\user\\Nicole\\data\\gis\\imagestoclip"

rasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters()
for raster in rasterlist:
    tx_name = os.path.join("C:\\user\\Nicole\\date\\clippedimages", "tx_" + raster)
    # If you want to maintain the clipping geometry:
    arcpy.Clip_management(raster, "#", tx_name, texas_shp, "-2147483647", "ClippingGeometry", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
    # If you don't:
    arcpy.Clip_management(raster, "#", tx_name, texas_shp, "-2147483647", "NONE", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
```

If you have other arcpy related questions, you might want to ask them in [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/), which is dedicated to GIS.